# Laptop 3.5mm jack sound quality is terrible

Tags: windows-10, audio, 3.5mm

A while ago I bought a Lenovo Flex 5 1570, running windows 10, as well as some audio things like Realtek HD Audio Manager and Dolby Audio. It's a great computer and all, but one day, after trying to get an experiment to work, there was a buzz when I connected to speakers using the 3.5mm jack and the quality of the sound when I listen using earbuds/headphones through the same port is really bad.

I don't understand exactly what happened, but when I listen to some songs, for example, the lead vocals are almost impossible to hear, but the background vocals and band are audible. Even then it sounds as if someone was playing music on the other side of a video call. It's very muffled and "chortled." I have the same results even with Dolby Audio disabled, and with various headphones, earbuds and speakers.

Do I need to send the computer in for a fix or is there anything I can do myself?

Thanks!

Comment: It almost sounds like you have set the gain to > 100% on the mixer so its causing distortion.  See if you can reduce this.

Comment: Is there any difference when using a different audio cable? *(usually this doesn't change anything, but recently I encountered a very poor quality 3.5mm cable that had a marked impact on sound quality)*

Comment: @davidgo I can't seem to find where to do this

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt This happens for all headphones I have tried